# Empty activity with API 7?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, android-activity

Why in Android Studio, the empty activity requires API 7(Without App Support Library)? Meanwhile the settings activity requires API 4.
Two questions:
1.Why empty activity requires API 7?
2.Why settings activity requires lower API than empty activity.(Settings activity looks more complicated than empty activity)
Here is a picture:
[image: Showing API]

Comment: What do you mean by "empty Activity"? As far as I'm aware the Activity class does not require any support library. AppCompatActivity does require API 7

Comment: @cricket_007, I am fairly certain he means the templates in Android Studio when hit File > New > New Project. I don't see where it lists the required API level though. Where did you see that?

Comment: @cricket_007 here is an picture.

Comment: Right... I just code my activities by hand. The templates probably use the support library, which is why they require those sdk versions

Comment: Its just fine that API 7 is required for appcompat. You are going to use much higher API level. Now a days we use MIN API 15.

Comment: Try create a new project with support library and after this delete 'compile 'supportv7...'' in build.gradle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's only because Android Studio thinks you have appcompat library enabled in your project. And no more.